# Android ic_drawer.png icon in white color?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am searching the android icon named ic_drawer.png but in white color. Where can i find it ?

Today, in example app, i have found this icon only in gray :

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Android Asset Studio has a very handy [Navigation Drawer Indicator Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg-history/280e7fd709d6cba589556229ed996d46973a41b3/asset-studio/dist/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html#theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C40), which allows you to set a custom color for your icon, and generate the required images in xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi and mdpi.

Bookmark the site, it has a lot of very useful tools for Android devs ;)

Comment: Is there any way to programmatically tint this icon? I want to change it to White or whatever color based on the user's theme preferences.

Comment: @kalehv you'll have to tint it yourself by using `findViewById()` to get android.R.id.home (or R.id.abs__home or R.id.home, depending on compatibility), and call `setColorFilter()` on that ImageView.  The HomeView does not apply any theme attributes.  If you're using ActionBarDrawerToggle class, you can obtain the drawable id from a theme attribute before instantiating the ABDT class, passing it the themed drawable resource id.

Comment: Dead link, but available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140712190315/http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-nav-drawer-indicator.html

Comment: The color selector in the archive.org was not working for me. I am using this instead http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html

Answer (score 3):

You can download icon's from this [link](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html).